# Date and time string to Datetime Timestamp Type in Spark scala dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, hive, timestamp

I have a date and time field in Spark data frame. Both are String type columns.
Want to combine both dates and times and later want to store it in Hive column with Timestamp Type.

eg: Date as 2018-09-10 and time as 140554(HHMMSS) or sometimes 95200(HMMSS)

Now When I use `concat(col("datefield"),lapd(col("timefield"),6,"0))`, I get the result as String
2018-09-10140554, but later when I convert it to Timestamp type it is not working properly.

Tried the below steps, but did not get the correct result. I just want to combine both dates and time string columns and make it a timestamp type.

1. to_timestamp with format YYYY-MM-ddHHMMSS
2. from_unixtimestamp(unix_timestamp)

Comment: hive timestamp format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss . String in this format is compatible with Hive timestamp

Comment: Nice first post, maybe you can add a longer code example of what you wrote?